# Install PHP LDAP module without root

Tags: php, linux, ldap

I have an existing linux server, with PHP already installed.  I just need to add in the [php_ldap module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php).  I do not have root/sudo access (no yum/apt-get), what is the best way to get it installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is none. Even if you get sources and compile it, you will still need to modify apache configuration to get it loaded. I suggest to talk to the admin of the server.

Answer (score 2):

He didn't said that he use apache. Theoretically, if the sources of web-server and php is compiled as the user running the web-server, that should works.

Comment: Judging from the general tone of the question I assume your solution is over-engineered :) Of course, he can compile his own webserver, php and all the modules, but I doubt this is the case here.

Comment: Sure it's not that easy, but that's a possible solution ;)

Comment: He can download lighty it's even easier and faster then apache.

Comment: python can run a web-server as current user with a really simple command : `python3 -m http.server` but unfortunately, there's no PHP. But it's a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I think it cannot be done without root privilege. If you cannot talk to your client you can look for a php library replacement instead. For example there is a JSON script replaceing the JSON extension.